# Issue with saving in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs, local-storage, slimerjs

I saved some information in `localStorage`, but after restarting, my script `localStorage` is empty. As I understand, for every start my script creates new `localStorage`.

Can I set path to `localStorage` directly? Maybe somebody knows where slimerjs saves `localStorage` on Windows 32?

I tried to use `webpage.offlineStoragePath = "./";` but  it not  working, I don't see a `localStorage` file. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The localStorage was empty because every start of slimerJs create new user. 
You should [create a permanent profile](https://docs.slimerjs.org/current/configuration.html#profiles).

Comment: Not so PhantomJS. The only thing that PhantomJS persists by default is the localStorage.